# Creating a Select/Dropdown list from navigation using JQuery for Mobile Version

Tags: jquery, combobox, listbox

I am working on a website which needs to be responsive. I want to convert the navigation into a  `<select>`. There can be any number of `<nav>` and any number of `<ul>` inside`<nav>`. I have used `for loops` to calculate number of `<nav> and <ul> inside <nav>`.

One is generating and the other one is not generating, please help me out to resolve this.

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetsubhajit/6JsHw/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because you're looking for `.children('ul')` and this only includes *immediate* descendants, however your second `nav` has a `div` wrapped around the `ul`...

You could change `.children` call to `.find` which looks for descendants at any depth

-- CUT HERE --

Alternative solution:

```
$('nav').each(function(navIndex, navElement) {

    $(this).find('ul').each(function(ulIndex, ulElement) {

        var $sel = $('<select name="nav'+navIndex+'-'+ulIndex+'" />');
        $sel.append('<option value="#">Go to...</option>');
        $sel.change(function() { document.location.href = this.value; });

        $(this).find('li>a').each(function(aIndex, aElement) {
            $sel.append('<option value="' + this.href + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
        });

        $(this).after($sel); // place this select after the ul...

    });
});
```

Comment: okay but sometimes <nav> is also not getting detected. how to get that solution?

Comment: how do you know `nav` is not beoing detected? `$('nav')` is pretty straight forward...

Comment: I just tested it with find() but still the same problem .Can you please test it once in fiddle as i am in big trouble. please check my question i have a fiddle link.

Comment: See the *alternative solution* in the answer - tested in http://jsfiddle.net/SYSac/ and working fine

Comment: Thank you for your help, let me give a try with this.